# How do I properly access props within createStyles?

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to figure out how to get access to `props` while within `createStyles` in my TypeScript project. I can't find any good examples.

Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to do:

```
type Props = {
  isActive: boolean;
}

const useStyles = makeStyles<Theme, Props>((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: props => ({
      border: `1px ${props.isActive ? `dashed` : `solid`} ${theme.palette.grey[500]}`,
  }),
);
```

I get this error when I try to use it that way:

```
Type '(props: Props) => { border: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
  Index signature is missing in type '(props: Props) => { border: string; }'.
```

The props do work if I remove the createStyles, but in my real code, I need createStyles in there for the typings to work properly.

Anyone have any ideas or examples of how to get the `props` working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not relevant as of TypeScript 3.5.  The type widening works properly and `createStyles` is no longer needed.